# Google Analytics API Custom Dimension name

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I'm using the Reporting API v4 and collecting information about Custom Dimensions.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=custom_variables_or_columns&jump=ga_dimensionxx

I am able to get dimensions like ga:dateHour but am unable to find a dimension that I can receive the "name". I want to pull in the names "zcode" and "ztest"
 described in this picture [Custom Dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rev6.png)

Am I missing a dimension or metric in this API to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name is used in the reporting interface only. In the API you address custom dimensions by the keyword "dimension" followed by their respective numeric index.

So in your example you would retrieve values for "zcode" by  querying "dimension1".

Comment: So I'm expected to know which index the "zcode" dimension is before making the API call? I can't make this more dynamic?

Comment: Yes and no respectively.

Comment: This is the correct answer. But if you really need to automate it before querying the Reporting API you can use the Management API to get a list of defined customDimensions in that property that should give you the name/scope/id of each dimension.... https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDimensions/list